# How to get different Object in click from request?

Tags: angular

With the help of the API, I get the data and get 20 objects. I display these elements on the page and each element has a button. I need a certain object to be displayed when I click, but unfortunately I only get the first object and I also get an error that points to `.find((element) => element.id === id)` and says:

```
TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the
types 'number' and 'ProductModel' have no overlap.
```

and second error:

```
this.productDifferent`: `Type 'ProductModel | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProductModel'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProductModel'.`
```

How to get clickable object on which I click?

Component.ts

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-products-list-api',
   templateUrl: './products-list-api.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./products-list-api.component.css']
})

export class ProductsListApiComponent implements OnInit {

   products: ProductModel[];
   productDifferent: ProductModel;

   constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.apiService.getAllProducts().subscribe((value) => {
       this.products = value
     });
   }

   addProductToList(id: ProductModel) {
     this.productDifferent = this.products.find((element) => element.id === id);
   }

}
```

Component.html

```html
<div>
   <div *ngFor="let product of products">
       <p> {{product.id}} {{product.title}} {{product.price}}
         <button (click)="addProductToList(product)"> Add to products list </button>
       <p>
   </div>
</div>
```

ProductModel.ts

```js
export interface ProductModel {
   id: number;
   title: string;
   price: number;
}
```

Service

```js
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

   getAllProducts(): Observable<ProductModel[]> {
      return this.httpClient.get<ProductModel[]>('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
   }

}
```

Comment: Same user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755198/data-transfer-between-components-only-the-object-with-the-first-id-is-selected pretty much same question. Would be best if you stick to 1 account and 1 question. Anyways seems like you are struggling with the basic fundamentals, you are still doing the function wrong for addProductToList accepts an object yet you are comparing id of number to object.

Comment: Well, no one can help me with this question, that's why I'm asking twice) Can you show me exactly how to do this because I have been struggling with this for a long time. Thank you very much

Comment: I believe I've given you an adequate information regarding to you question and a way forward... I think the problem is you're expecting someone to write you a full code answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of the errors:

```
S2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the
types 'number' and 'ProductModel' have no overlap.
```

This occurs because you have the variable `id` which is type `ProductModel`, but you are comparing it to `element.id` which if of type `number`.  The error tells you that your condition will never be true because a `ProductModel` can never be equal to a `number`.

Your mistake is here:

```js
   addProductToList(id: ProductModel) {
     this.productDifferent = this.products.find((element) => element.id === id);
   }
```

The variable you call `id` is really a `ProductModel`, so in your `.find()`, you need to compare against the `product.id`, not the ProductModel.  To fix, just rename your variable and compare against the `id` property:

```js
   addProductToList(product: ProductModel) {
     this.productDifferent = this.products.find((element) => element.id === product.id);
   }
```

---

```
this.productDifferent`: `Type 'ProductModel | undefined' is not assignable to type 
'ProductModel'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ProductModel'.
```

This occurs because you've defined `productDifferent` to be of type `ProductModel`, but the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns `ProductModel|undefined`.  That's exactly what the error is telling.

You actually don't even need to use `.find()`, your function accepts the clicked `ProductModel` as a parameter, so just use it!

```js
   addProductToList(product: ProductModel) {
     this.productDifferent = product;
   }
```